# Start bounty does not appear on a question, without any reason?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have posted a question on stackOverflow. This is the link:

[document.write creates content out of the required div container in opera and msie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853554/document-write-creates-content-out-of-the-required-div-container-in-opera-and-ms)

This question does not have start bounty link to it. There is no reason for this to happen. I have 341 reputation points. All other questions asked by me have that link, but this one does not. It is completely inexplicable!

Any suggestions regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too recently-asked to be eligible for a bounty. From [the bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> #### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked. [...]

Comment: 2 days have already passed. And there comes a line saying "This question is eligible for bounty after x days". That line also didn't come

Comment: That question was asked at server time 2012-01-13 16:10:12Z, you posted this question as server time 2012-01-15 08:23:54Z. It's only been 40 hours. And I'm not sure when that message is displayed, but it's not always.